# How do I specify a keys password with MSBuild for the purpose of using Hudson?

Tags: .net, msbuild, hudson, passwords, strongname

We have just setup our hudson server to build .NET projects which seems to be working fine, however for projects that require a password when signing the assemblies I can not figure out how to tell hudson what the password is?

For us the password is asked the first time a developer checks out the source code and they open with visual studio, how is this stored? Can we just place a secret file somewhere on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this by logging into the server as the same user that starts tomcat (I had to alter the configuration and setup a dedicated user).

I then manually built the project which raised the dialog for asking for the password, however, this seems like a hack and not something I can put into a script, what happens if our build server changes, shouldn't I be able to specify this in the source tree somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You have to sign it with a certificate that is issued from your CA and stored in the cert store of your build server.  The self-issue test ones that VS makes have to have a gui pop-up for the password and the build server cannot do that since it is a service.

Answer (score 0):

On my Vista machine, I was able to turn on the feature 'allow this service to interact with the desktop' and then when the build popped up the dialog, Windows told me about it, and allowed me to switch over to the 'service' desktop, in order to click 'yes'.

Comment: You can't do this on a server as there is no user logged in.